# Inequality with limsup from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

For any two real sequences $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\},$ prove that $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)\leqslant\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n+\limsup_{n\to \infty}b_n$$provided the sum on the right is not of the form $\infty-\infty.$

**Proof:** Let $\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n=\sup A=a^*$ and $\limsup_{n\to \infty}b_n=\sup B=b^*$ and $a_n+b_n:=c_n,$ $\limsup_{n\to \infty}c_n=\sup C$. We must prove that $\sup C\leqslant a^*+b^*$.

We'll consider case where $a^*,b^*\in \mathbb{R}^1$ because if at least one of them $+\infty$ is obvious.

Taking any $x\in C$ $\exists$${n_k}$ s.t. $\lim_{k\to \infty}c_{n_k}=\lim _{k\to \infty}(a_{n_k}+b_{n_k})=x$. Also we know that $\lim_{k\to \infty}a_{n_k}\leqslant a^*$ and $\lim_{k\to \infty}b_{n_k}\leqslant b^*$.
Cases when the limits of $\{a_{n_k}\}$ and $\{b_{n_k}\}$ are finite and $\leqslant a^*$ and $\leqslant b^*$ are obvious. In all above cases we got that $x\leqslant a^*+b^*.$

If at least on these limits is infinite (let $\lim_{k\to \infty}a_{n_k}=-\infty$) then $\lim_{k\to \infty}(-a_{n_k})=+\infty$ and we conclude that $\lim_{k\to \infty}b_{n_k}=+\infty$ and $+\infty\in B$. Hence $b^*\in \mathbb{R}^1$ is not $\sup B$. Contradiction.

Cases where at least on them ($a^*$, $b^*$) is $-\infty$ is also obvious.

Can anybody to verify my proof? I know that there is a simple proof but this solution belongs to me.

Comment: The first sentence of you proof is nonsense. What is $A, B,C$? How does your book define $\limsup$? Don't skip the obvious cases - they are not always obvious. Write $c_n:=a_n+b_n$. The $:=$ means "I'm defining the left side as..." not "I'm defining one side."

Comment: $\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n:=\sup A$ where $A$ the set of all subsequential limits of $\{a_n\}$. This definition from Rudin. It's not nonsense! What's next?

Comment: The set $B$ and $C$ defines also like $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n=a^*\in \mathbb{R}, \quad \limsup_{n\to \infty}b_n=b^*\in \mathbb{R}.$$
For any $\delta>0$ by property b) of Theorem 3.17 exists $N_1$ such that $n\geqslant N_1$ implies that $a_n<a^*+\delta$ and exists $N_2$ such that $n\geqslant N_2$ implies that $b_n<b^*+\delta$.

Then for $n>\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ we got $a_n+b_n<a^*+b^*+2\delta$.

Hence $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)\leqslant a^*+b^*+2\delta$$ since $\delta$ is arbitrary then $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)\leqslant a^*+b^*$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing this down a bit more detailed includes a shitload of subsequences, but I think the idea is quite approachable: Translate everything into converging sequences, then see where you can do the inequalities.

The case where one of them is $\pm\infty$ should be clear, therfore let both $\limsup a_n=:A$ and $\limsup b_n=:B$ be finite. Define:

$$
c_n:=a_n+b_n
$$
$$
c_{n_k}\overset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} C=:\limsup_n c_n
$$
$$
a_{n_{k_i}}\overset{i\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} A':=\limsup_k a_{n_k}\leq A
$$
$$
b_{n_{k_{i_j}}}\overset{j\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow} B':=\limsup_i b_{n_{k_i}}\leq B
$$The crux is to observe, that $\limsup_k x_{n_k}\leq\limsup_nx_n$, which is clear from the definition $\limsup_k x_{n_k}=\lim_k( \sup_{l\geq k} x_{n_l})
$, as the set you take the sup over will get bigger if you take the original sequence instead of the subsequence.

Using this and the fact, that subsequences of convergent sequences converge to the same value, you have:
$$
C=\lim_k c_{n_k}=\lim_i c_{n_{k_i}}=\lim_j c_{n_{k_{i_j}}}=\lim_j (a_{n_{k_{i_j}}}+b_{n_{k_{i_j}}})=\lim_j a_{n_{k_{i_j}}}+\lim_jb_{n_{k_{i_j}}}
$$
$$
=A'+B'\leq A +B
$$
as stated.